# Converting CURL command to .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, curl

I'm totally new to CURL and would like to know how to convert the following command to .net using httpWebRequest (that's my guess)

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8042/instances --data-binary @CT.X.1.2.276.0.7230010.dcm
```

I really haven't tried anything as frankly I have no idea where to start.

Comment: What parts of this curl command specifically are unclear to you for translating to a HttpWebRequest?

Comment: If you dont know where to start, you have not done enough research.  This is not a tutorial site or code conversion service.

Comment: [First item in list](https://www.bing.com/search?q=translate%20curl%20commands%20to%20response%20calls%20c%23&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=translate%20curl%20commands%20to%20response%20calls%20c%23&sc=0-44&sk=&cvid=A65D24A2F51F4CCCB668804175612970)

Comment: What is the dataType  of data-binary? you can customize the example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class, and define url, and contentType for POST method.

Comment: @M.Hassan the dataType is DICOM image file

Comment: @JonathonChase mainly this part   `--data-binary @CT.X.1.2.276.0.7230010.dcm`

Comment: So, you need to upload that DICOM image to the the requested url. Use this code to upload file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/567460/3142139

Comment: @ranasrule You'll want to read the file (`CT.X.1.2.276.0.7230010.dcm`) to a byte array with `File.ReadAllBytes`. Set the request's content type to `multipart/form-data` and write the byte array to the request stream.

Comment: @M.Hassan I also then need to check the response field of "Status" which will be JSON like this `{
  "ID" : "e87da270-c52b-4f2a-b8c6-bae25928d0b0",
  "Path" : "/instances/e87da270-c52b-4f2a-b8c6-bae25928d0b0",
  "Status" : "Success"
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with based on the example posted by @M.Hassan

```
Public Function UPLOAD_FILE(filepath As String) As String
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8042/instances ")
    request.Method = "POST"
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Console.WriteLine((CType(response, HttpWebResponse)).StatusDescription)
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()
    Return responseFromServer
End Function
```